# When FormControl is disabled, it is not listed in this.form.value

Tags: angular, typescript

I have added this disabled FormControl for a checkbox:

```js
newsletter: new FormControl({value: true, disabled: true}),
```

I cannot find its value in `this.form.value`. However, if I set `disabled` as `false`, the value appears.

Whether disabled or not, I want its value in `this.form.value`. How do I do this?

See [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-disabled-yrbkvh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the desired behavior for disabled controls.

Your alternative is to use `getRawValue()` which returns every values, even the disabled ones.